# Flutter material 3 messing up the UI

Tags: flutter

After updating the last flutter update the text fields in my flutter app got messed up a little I don't know why.

this is how it looks with material 3 before the updating

[image]

and this is how it looks like after the update

[image]

I'm trying to figure out why it happened.

Comment: It'd be very helpful, if you would post the relevant code of the problem

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi I just want to understand why it happened. I'm not looking for a fix.

Comment: @Toxicless We would still need to see the relevant code (a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to explain why it's happened.

Comment: Please see if any of these breaking changes is related to your problem. https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes#released-in-flutter-316

Comment: Code is still required to understand the problem, as it appears the problem does not happen with regular use of text fields.

Answer (score 0):

just add material 3 as false in Theme Data of your main Function

Comment: I know that it fixes it and i tried some other ways to fix it and they worked I just want to understand why it happened. Im not looking for a fix.

Comment: google added material 3 design in flutter from version 3.16 as default https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91605

Comment: He said he already used Material 3 before upgrading to 3.16.